# Why should we adopt the cumulative universe convention?

Tags: type-theory, intuitionistic-logic, homotopy-type-theory

In various sources on intuitionistic type theory, the universe of types is taken to be *cumulative*, i.e. $A:\mathcal U _i$ implies $A:\mathcal U_j$ whenever $i\le j$.

The question is: why do we have to assume that? Is there any unavoidable difficulty if we do not use it (that way elements always have unique types)? And, what are the subtleties involved in each situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done because it seems natural, and it avoids some tedium of having to explicitly [`lift`](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/repos/lib/src/Level.agda) terms in one universe to a higher universe. It's essentially just a subtyping constraint, and instead of having implicit coercions, you can have explicit coercions, i.e. the `lift`s. I believe one of the reasons Agda *doesn't* have cumulativity is that it doesn't interact well with universe polymorphism (or rather its interactions were not well understood), but you should check that. Subtyping, in general, often leads to gnarly complexities.

Comment: Note though that Agda's non-cumulativity predates its universe polymorphism. It might be more that polymorphism makes things tolerable enough for no one to bother working out cumulativity. It is a good example of why you'd still want cumulativity even _with_ polymorphism, though, because it reduces the number of universe indices you need to track. Rather than one index for each possible universe in the definition, and using $\sqcup$, you just choose one 'big enough' index for everything.